# move_uploaded_file not working despite correct path and existing file

Tags: php

I'm really struggling with an issue relating the move_uploaded_file function of php.

The path should be correct, but see yourself:

```
$imgDir     = "../img/".$CATEGORY;
$fileName   = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$maxsize    = 800;
$compQuality= 75;
if(!is_dir($imgDir)) {
    mkdir($imgDir.'/tn', 0777, true);
    chmod($imgDir, 0777);       
    chmod($imgDir, 0777);
}

$imgDir     = $imgDir."/";
$imgTnDir   = $imgDir."tn/";
```

I have also tested it by echo-ing everything and it seems to work, but when it comes to the move_uploaded_file it still does not work, even though I test if the file really exists:

```
if(file_exists($imgDir.$fileName)) {
    $status = "The file ".$fileName." already exists, please choose a different title.";
} 

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imgDir.$fileName)) {
    $status = "File upload failed, sorry.";
}   

if(!empty($status)) { 
    echo $status;
    exit();
}
```

I hope that someone can help me. If you want I can print anything out you need or give you more snippets of the code. The var $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] does not only exist, but has a proper name by the way.

Also I have checked the php.ini and both uploading is allowed and the size is surely set high enough.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you get an error in your logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you have the right path in $imgDir. You can try:

```
if(!is_writable($imgDir)) { exit('CANNOT_WRITE_IN_DIR'); }
```

and also you can use an absolute path, like this:

```
$imgDir = __DIR__ . "/../img/".$CATEGORY;
```

Comment: Thank you. You actually instandly found the issue. It's obivously not writeable. It's weird cause I actually gave rights via putty, so I excluded this possibility, but ... I never checked like this.